# Bash shell script of a menu with three options

Tags: bash, shell

I have this exercise: Create a BASH shell script "menu", which accepts as an argument a file "listino.txt" structured as follows:

cost quantity code
01953 2 15
07934 1 20
084Gd 10 30
9038H 1 5

and that implements the following functions accessible from a menu:

1. Search - Asks the user for a string to search for in the entire price list and performs the search
2. Add - Asks the user for the product code to add (first field of the price list) and the quantity of items desired, verifies the choices made and stores them in a cart file
3. Remove - a product from the cart

But the delete function doesn't work for me can you help me (it's the last case)

```
#!/bin/bash
cat listino.txt
echo "Vuoi fare : ricerca/inserimento/eliminazione? "
read answer
case $answer in
   ricerca)
      echo "Inserisci stringa  da cercare:\n"
      read stringa
      if awk "${stringa}" listino.txt
      then
        echo "Stringa e presente in listino"
        else
        echo "Stringa non presente in listino"
        fi
       
      ;;
   inserimento)
      echo "Inserisci codice prodotto:\n"
      read codice
      echo "Inserisci quantita prodotto:\n"
      read quantita
      a="$codice    $quantita"
      echo $a >> carrello.txt
      ;;

   eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      a="$prodottoEliminare"
      for stringa in carrello.txt ; do
      if [ "$stringa"=="$a" ];
          then
              echo "Elemento cancellato"
          else
              echo "Elemento non cancellato"
       fi
      done
      ;;   
*) 
esac
```

Thank you

Comment: You should give more detail on `delete function doesn't work`.

Comment: `for stringa in carrello.txt` will give back only one string, "`carrello.txt`". It doesn't read the file. You could use something like `for stringa in $(cat carrello.txt)`.

Comment: the delete function is written above, the problem is that it doesn't delete anything in the carello.txt file

Comment: @cornux it doesn't delete anything in my carrello.txt file

Comment: @saretta2, your code didn't include anything to delete, only `echo` for both cases. My comment was not specifically about deleting, but about a wrong loop. What I would actually do is to replace everything from the 3rd row on with: `sed -i "/$prodottoEliminare/d" carrello.txt`. That is: search a line where `$prodottoEliminare` occurs and delete it (`/d`), in place (`-i`).

Comment: @cornuz okay but then I get this error "sed: 1: "cart.txt": command c expects \ followed by text" and it doesn't delete anything from the file for me.

Comment: @saretta2 Does the product code that you enter include a `/`? That is the only reason I could think of that would make that fail.

Comment: @cornuz this is the modification made    eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      if sed -i '/${prodottoEliminare}/d' carrello.txt  
      then
              echo "Elemento cancellato"
      else
              echo "Elemento non cancellato"
      fi
      ;;

Comment: and the cart file contains this : 084Gd 2
01953 1. i'm using the mac shell

Comment: Ah, no, I meant, replace the whole loop, from `for` to `done` with the `sed` command. No loop, no `if`. The only disadvantage is that you can't `echo` a message, to know whether it was found and removed.

Comment: @cornuz eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      sed  -i '/${prodottoEliminare}/d' carrello.txt  
      ;; I get the same message

Comment: @cornuz seen and tried but I get the same message but it's not that it doesn't work from mac doing so, because some commands from mac don't work

Comment: @cornuz yes thank you very much with the new va part, then it was a problem with the mac...thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in different ways.

One is

```
   eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      sed -i "/$prodottoEliminare/d" carrello.txt
      ;;
```

If you want some feedback you can first test with `grep` (or with `awk` as you did in `ricerca)`) and then delete with `sed`:

```
   eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      if grep -q "$prodottoEliminare" carrello.txt; then
          sed -i "/$prodottoEliminare/d" carrello.txt
          echo "Elemento cancellato"
      else
          echo "Elemento non cancellato"
      fi
      ;;
```

From the comments in your question it seems the `sed` command doesn't work on your Mac. I don't know enough about Macs, but you can always replace it with something else. A solution that comes to my mind is to use `grep` again, but reversed (to find anything but that string):

```
   eliminazione)
      echo "quale prodotto vuoi eliminare:"
      read prodottoEliminare
      if grep -q "$prodottoEliminare" carrello.txt; then
          grep -qv "$prodottoEliminare" carrello.txt > carrello.txt.tmp
          mv carrello.txt.tmp carrello.txt
          echo "Elemento cancellato"
      else
          echo "Elemento non cancellato"
      fi
      ;;
```